# How to read the content of a http.IncomingMessage (ReadableStream) without consuming it in node.js?

Tags: node.js, sockets, proxy, stream, http-proxy

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm trying to create a proxy in node.js where I can inspect the content of an HTTP request before forwarding it to my target server.

**What I have tried so far:**

I have created this function "getContent(req)" which gives me the content of the request, so that I can inspect it and decide if I want to forward it to the target server.

```
function getContent(req) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        let body = [];
        let textDecoder = new TextDecoder();

        req.on('data', (chunk) => {
            body.push(textDecoder.decode(chunk));
        });
        req.on('end', () => {
            resolve(body.join(''));
        });
    });
}
```

**The problem I'm stuck with:**

The function works and I do get the content of the request, but this consumes the stream, so I can no longer forward the http.IncomingMessage to my target server.

Code of the proxy that will forward the request for reference:

```
const http = require('http');
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
    target: 'http://127.0.0.1:7545'
});

var server = http.createServer(
    async function (req, res) {
        /** If I remove this line, the proxy request forwarding works,
         *  but I need to inspect the content of the request before forwarding! */
        let content = await getContent(req);

        console.log(`${content} - processing request!`);
        proxy.web(req, res);
    });
```

So in conclusion, how to read the content of a http.IncomingMessage (ReadableStream) without consuming it in node.js, so that I can then still forward the request to a target server?

Comment: looks like it cannot be cloned. try this: [Make a Node js proxy with multiple targets depending on the body of the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64783089/make-a-node-js-proxy-with-multiple-targets-depending-on-the-body-of-the-request)

Comment: Ah I see, so it's impossible to avoid consuming the stream, so the intended way is to manually make a duplicate of the request.

Thanks, you can post that as an answer and I will accept it!

Comment: it seems that way. No need, it's better to upvote the linked post, and I had nothing new to add, so I didn't answer